# echo input tag with oninput validity in php

Tags: php, html, html-table

Others things it seem fine but once it involve function in the element the echo php doesnt work. For example this one

```
<?php 
    $output = '';
    $output .'<tr>
                <td>Written Score</td>
                <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Written Score" type="number" name="written" id="written" min="0" max="100" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" /></td>
            </tr>';

    echo $output;
?>
```

it seem the oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" is make this code doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape those single quotes inside the string assignment. Change `'` to `\'`:

```
"validity.valid||(value=\'\');"
```